# Is it possible to use the bluetooth adapter from my logitech keyboard to connect headset?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth

So, as titled.

I have a bluetooth wireless keyboard that goes with the bluetooth adapter from Logitech 2 years ago.
Recently I just brought a bluetooth headset from other company, but I wonder if I can reuse the bluetooth adapter from Logitech to use the headset?

I don't seems to find an option in my control panel that allows me to add the headset device....
Or the blue adapter that comes with Logitech is only able to connect to the logitech keyboard?
In that case, if I buy a bluetooth adapter, will it possible to share 1 bluetooth adapter with two device? (1 to 2? not 1 to 1?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the wireless adapter for the keyboard might use proprietary methods to connect and  so it may not be trivial (or even possible) to reuse it with the headset. You can however get a generic bluetooth adapter and use that to connect to the Headset.

As for the 1-2 connection, bluetooth has some facilities for such things but the default is 1-1. Besides, as mentioned above it is likely impossible to change which adapter the keyboard would connect to, you need 2 usb ports to use both.

Comment: I guess my only choice is to buy a bluetooth adapter then... I was thinking other alterative...  make PC stream audio to android (yes, not android to PC, is PC to andriod), then use pair my bluetooth to android ....so I have bluetooth connection to my headset? Oh well... Thanks for your answer~

Comment: Well you could do that using [DLNA](http://www.which.co.uk/technology/tv-and-dvd/guides/what-is-dlna/) I guess, but if you are actually sitting at your desk it does sound more convoluted than necessary.